# KDE Neon Upgrade to 22.04 Fails Due to Unofficial Package Issues

Tags: ubuntu, upgrade, dist-upgrade, ppa, kde-neon

I'm facing an issue while trying to upgrade my KDE Neon system to version 22.04. The upgrade process halts with an error message suggesting an issue with unofficial packages. Here is the essence of the error message (originally not in English):

"Impossible to evaluate the upgrade. An unsolvable problem occurred during the calculation of the upgrade. This was probably caused by: * unofficial packages not from Ubuntu. Please use the command 'ppa-purge' from the package 'ppa-purge' to remove the packages from a PPA Launchpad repository, then try to relaunch the upgrade."

I haven't taken any steps yet such as using `sudo ppa-purge`, `sudo apt-get autoremove`, `sudo apt-get autoclean`, or `sudo apt-get update`. I'm seeking guidance before proceeding because I'm concerned about potentially causing further issues or damaging my current install.

I also have this popping after I close everything related to the upgrade:

`Unit packagekit.socket does not exist, proceeding anyway. Created symlink /run/systemd/system/packagekit.socket → /dev/null. Created symlink /run/systemd/system/packagekit.service → /dev/null. Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit packagekit.service is masked. Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit packagekit.service is masked. Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit packagekit.service is masked. Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit packagekit.service is masked. Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit packagekit.service is masked. Error: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.systemd1.UnitMasked: Unit packagekit.service is masked. exitMainLoopMidFlight None None Removed /run/systemd/system/packagekit.service. Removed /run/systemd/system/packagekit.socket.`

My questions are:

1. How can I safely identify and remove unofficial packages that are preventing the upgrade?
2. Are there precautions I can take to ensure that system cleanup will not affect my current setup?
3. What logs or additional information should I check to understand the specific cause of the upgrade failure?

I'm looking for the safest path to upgrade my system, avoiding a fresh install if possible. Thank you for any advice or insights you can provide.